# Ruby on Rails v5.1 and Paperclip gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing, paperclip

I am working on the Rails application, using Ubuntu. Everything was fine until I have tried to add images to the website using paperclip gem and Imagemagick.

I have implemented the code as required, including models, controllers and probably views, and when I click the create/submit button all the fields in the form get accepted and updated in the database, including images. But on the website it gives the following error:

```
undefined method `image' for nil:NilClass
```

and this is the line which gives the error:

```
<%= image_tag @current_user.image.url(:medium) %>
```

I have already tried to drop the database and to work with new migration, but the error still rises up when I try to create new user.

Comment: The error is saying `@current_user` is nil and doesn't have an image method (or attribute), can you check the value of `@current_user`?

Comment: #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, email: "newuser@tester.com", created_at: "2017-12-09 15:39:00", updated_at: "2017-12-09 15:39:00", username: "newuser", image_file_name: "icon5.png", image_content_type: "image/png", image_file_size: 61412, image_updated_at: "2017-12-09 15:39:00", description: "First User">]>

Comment: this is the database entry when i submit the form

Comment: You need to check the value of `@current_user` at the moment you're rendering the `image_tag` helper. As you're using an ActiveRecord::Relation of Users, it's a relationship of multiple objects, not a single one.

Comment: how can I do that please?

Comment: If you're getting a NoMethodError you can use the repl in the view displayed, there check the needed variables, even it gives you an advice of the present variables. http://prntscr.com/hl85vs

Comment: Well I got the same thing as in the screenshot, which is 'nil', and it says in the view that it requires following Request

Parameters:

{"id"=>"newuser"}
also, I am using devise for users, but the error shows on other parts of the website, not just users page

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `@current_user` is an `ActiveRecord::Relation`, but you need a record to access `image`.  Since it looks like you only have one item in the relation, you can access the first (and only) record with the `first` method:

```
<%= image_tag @current_user.first.image.url(:medium) %>
```

However, a better approach would be to do this in the Controller or Helper that sets `@current_user` in the first place.  You could simply append `.first` to the expression that you use to set `@current_user`.

One caveat, by appending `.first` you will always be selecting the first record in the relation. If your query returns multiple records, all of the records expect the first one will be ignored. This is not normally a problem if your query searches for something unique, like an id.

Comment: how do You mean one item in the relation, if you mean one user, that is currently, since I had to drop the db, if you mean one user will have one image, then your answer might work

Comment: I mean whatever you are using to compute `@current_user` is returning only one user record.  You can select that record with the `first` method.  The real issue here is with the code you are using to compute `@current_user` not with your view.  You may want to post that code in your question.

Comment: I got it to work eventually, but new problem I have got is with the size of the image, it is off even when I change it in the model. Well now I have to fix this. Thank You all for Your time and help, I appreciate it, eventually the problem was in the variables I used.

Comment: No worries.  Feel free to accept and/or upvote SO answers that help you.